# Filtering in pandas by condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter, conditional-statements, minimum

I have a dataframe sample looks like below. first row is header.

```
a  b   c   d   e
x  1   10  4   asd
y  3   12  5   aqe
z  4   14  6   rty
t  6   12  4   abd
v  7   4   8   yul
```

I would like the find a column members by filtering d column by its minimum value. I tried the sort it and select the 0. element but column may have 2 minimum values like in the sample.

Output should be "x" and "t"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select column `a` and last convert to `list`:

```
L = df.loc[df['d'] == df['d'].min(), 'a'].tolist()
print (L)
['x', 't']
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['d'] == df['d'].min())
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: d, dtype: bool
```